# Spark Dataframe union is so slow

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use different Linear Regression models transform dataframes and get some frames.

```
val frames:Array[DataFrame] = new Array[DataFrame](rows.length)
for(i <- 0 to rows.length - 1) {
  val userid = rows.apply(i).getString(0)
  val frame = filterByUserId(userid, data)
  val userModel = LinearRegressionModel.load(userModelPath+userid)
  if(userModel!=null) {
    println(i+": predicte "+userid)
    userModel.setFeaturesCol("feature")
    val prediction = userModel.transform(frame)
    frames.update(i, prediction)
  }
}
```

And then, I want to union this frames to evaluate the predictions.

```
var frame1 = frames.apply(0)
for(i <- 1 to frames.size - 1)
  frame1 = frame1.union(frames.apply(i))
frame1
```

But the union operation is so slow, why? How to solve this problem?

Comment: this is not 1 union operation; it is `frames.size - 1` union operations...

Comment: How do you measure the performance? If I'm not mistaken, `frame1` is another DataFrame so nothing's really executed until...you trigger an action. What's the action?

Comment: Can you try changing the partition of each dataframe you are doing union to some constant value (for example 2). If it increases the performance, then the partition can be get by number of cores present in the cluster.